# Doctrine 2: How to get association configurations to create "not null" columns?

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am trying to get Doctrine 2 to create all columns with "not null" set. I don't want any null values in the MySQL (or whatever) database. According to the documentation, not null is default for fields created through Doctrine. However, that does not seem to extend to associations. Technically I am doing this through Symfony 2, but the problem is with how I am using the included Doctrine 2.

Here are the two sanitized entities I'm working with (in YAML):

```
App\Entity\Foo:
  type: entity
  table: foo
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: '64'
  manyToOne:
    bar:
      targetEntity: Bar

App\Entity\Bar:
  type: entity
  table: bar
  id:
    id:
      type: integer
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
  fields:
    name:
      type: string
      length: '64'
```

And the resulting create and alter table queries:

```
CREATE TABLE bar (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
CREATE TABLE foo (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  bar_id INT DEFAULT NULL, name VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  INDEX IDX_8C73652189A253A (bar_id), PRIMARY KEY(id)) ENGINE = InnoDB;
ALTER TABLE foo ADD CONSTRAINT FK_8C73652189A253A FOREIGN KEY (bar_id) REFERENCES bar(id)
```

I have tried searching through the documentation for answers, tried setting "nullable: false" in the manyToOne /bar entry, and creating a separate field for the "bar_id" (which came closest but resulted in entities with both setBarId and setBar methods, trading one problem for another).

Answer (score 2):

From my experience there are two ways.
First :  Implement bidirectional association as listed in manual http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/association-mapping.html?highlight=constraint#one-to-many-bidirectional. And than in join column add - nullable: false

Second: to add your column to section fields and there will appear ability to place all options you need to add for this join column

Answer (score 1):

Try setting nullable as a property of the joinColumn:

```
App\Entity\Foo:
  type: entity
  [...]
  manyToOne:
   bar:
    targetEntity: Bar
    joinColumn:
      nullable: false
```

Comment: I was not able to find this in the yaml section of the doctrine documentation though. I think the annotations reference is more complete: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn